# Switching between images with a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a webpage in which I need to create a button that will switch the image displayed, 
the image is a schematic of a building so I will need a button to select between levels, level 1, 2 ect...

On top of that I need a button that will toggle another image relative to the current image displayed on page, this image will toggle some extra details inside the image, but the button only has to link to another image file so thats no drama.

Any help will be appreciated as I have followed a few ideas with no success.

I'm thinking javascript would be easier for this project.

Thanks again.

Comment: _"on top of that i need a button that will toggle another image relative to the current image displayed on page, this image will toggle some extra detail inside the image, but the button only has to link to another image file"_ Can you include `html`, `css`, `javascript` that you have tried to solve issue at Question?

Comment: You are correct - Javascript would certainly be the right choice but the question is far too broad

Comment: *i have followed a few ideas in here* - What did you try? *with no success* -  What happened and how is that not what you want?

Comment: I honestly cannot tell from your description exactly what you need. Does the button scroll through levels like a carousel? Extra detail? Have you even drawn a simple picture of what you want this UI to look like and do? Go get something like Balsamiq, sketch your idea, open js fiddle and try to get somethign started.

Comment: ill draw something up for you all in a bit

but basically think of an image on a page with a radio button below it that selects a different image source when clicked 

I was able to get the image to change with the click of a mouse but not with an external button

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Xj5Wk/ 

something like this could work for me but separate buttons would be needed to select between different levels of the building

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way for a beginner is to use it this method:

For example you have a folder with images. And you have a page with one image that you want to switch and a button that will toggle it.

This is not functional example but it might give you an idea:

HTML:

```
<img src="img/img01.jpg">
<button id="toggler"></button>
```

JS:

```
var button = document.querySelector('#toggler');

button.onclick = function(){
 var img = document.querySelector('img');
 img.src = "new img url"
}
```

Now, jQuery might be easier way for you to do this, but it is not very different from this example.

Comment: Thanks for the help

https://jsfiddle.net/0s2nuLhc/4/
this is what i have thus far, i know its very crude, is there anyway to nest the functions together ?

Comment: @RobertLee How do you want to nest them? What effect do you want to achieve? You can make it all to be just 1 button and 1 function. I will provide more info when I get back.

Comment: i need to have a separate button for each different image, 
if  a new function is required for each button and img src i'm happy with that. Although coming to my next part, i somehow need to be able to toggle a different image to appear which is related to what image is currently being displayed on the page, i.e every image that is displayed has another image that goes with it, this new image will take the place on the one that was on the screen. Sorry if this is a confusing question, my knowledge on all this is very minimal

Comment: I see, ok, I ll provide codepen/jsfiddle after lunch

Comment: Update
this is what i have so far https://jsfiddle.net/0s2nuLhc/23/

although my 'button 4' function is not working 
this is the function that is suppose to change the image relative to another on the page

Comment: http://codepen.io/kunokdev/pen/XjZkvP   This might help. There are many ways to achieve same thing, the example I provided is quick way to achieve this, but there are many more better ways, but this might give you idea.

Comment: Thats great thank you, i'll keep at it and see how i go,
Thanks!

Comment: i've got a new problem, i'm trying to use javascript if a certain img src is displayed on a page, i want a button to press which will load a totally different image when that certain image is displayed, it takes the place of the old image on the page
thats what code ive got  below but its not working, it is the 4th button toggeler 3
https://jsfiddle.net/0s2nuLhc/27/

Comment: Here is example with changing whole HTML for one of divs: https://jsfiddle.net/ur5uxt1e/5/ Note that you can also use += operator for appending.